# How to remove "Hello Member" in Woocommerce Checkout page?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, styles, checkout

i want to remove this area, in checkout page, but every my try was not working. I tryed to insert this CSS:

```
.avada-myaccount-user-column .username {
display:none;
}
```

[image]
[image]

This is [product](https://huskypalace.com/product/siberian-husky-adoption-deposit/) that trying to insert into cart, for testing purposes. Someone to help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.avada-myaccount-user-column .username` will not work because `.username` is not a child of `.avada-myaccount-user-column`.

Change your CSS to:

```
.avada-myaccount-user-column.username {
    display: none;
}
```

This example means the first class requires the second class for it to be affected.

Answer (score 4):

```
.avada-myaccount-user-column.username {
display:none;
}
```

Use that ^. When you have two classes in a DIV you want to target, you don't have spaces between them to target. If it doesn't work, it's possible to override with custom templates. See https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/ for theme overrides. Since you're using a premium theme, their support should be able to help you. If you do theme overrides, you should do them in a child theme so you can update the parent theme gracefully as updates come out.